# Improperly updating state with async / await in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

My goal is to add a new stock - which consists of a quote, chart, meta info into their respective arrays in the component state, by calling my `_addStock()` function in `componentDidMount`. However, after looping through and calling `_addStock`, I only have 1 stock within each respective array.

I can get this working by adding a delay via setTimeouts between each `_addStock` call - but that defeats the purpose of promises.

I thought with async / awaits, JavaScript would "synchronously" execute code. However, it seems like the `setState` is only being called once when I'm calling `_addStock` multiple times.

What's going on?

`_fetchMeta`, `_fetchQuote`, ...etc return promises.

```
...

// this is what my state ends up looking like, only 1 per key when I'm expecting 4.
this.state = {
    stocks: [
        {
            symbol: 'MSFT',
            display: '...',
            color: '...'
        }
    ],
    metas: [
        {
            symbol: 'MSFT',
            name: '...',
            description: '...'
        }
    ],
    quotes: [
        {
            symbol: 'MSFT',
            price: '...',
            change: '...'
        }
    ],
    charts: [
        {
            symbol: 'MSFT',
            data: "..."
        }
    ]
}

//...

_addStock = async symbol => {
    const { metas, quotes, charts, stocks } = this.state;

    // check if stock already exists
    const hasStock = stocks.filter(s => s.symbol === symbol).length;
    if (hasStock) {
        return;
    }

    const meta = await this._fetchMeta(symbol);
    const quote = await this._fetchQuote(symbol);
    const chart = await this._fetchChart(symbol);
    const stock = {
        symbol: symbol.toUpperCase(),
        color: setStockColor(),
        display: true
    };

    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        metas: [...metas, meta],
        quotes: [...quotes, quote],
        charts: [...charts, chart],
        stocks: [...stocks, stock]
    });
};

//...

componentDidMount() {
    const initStocks = ["FB", "MSFT", "NVDA", "AAPL"];
    initStocks.forEach(s => this._addStock(s));
}
```

Comment: all the `_addStock` calls are being done "at once" ... do they need to wait for the previous to "finish" before the next one is started?

Comment: if you do need to do "one at a time" ... `initStocks.reduce((p, s) => p.then(() => this._addStock(s)), Promise.resolve());` however, `componentDidMount` will "return" before any _addStock is finished - not sure if that's going to be an issue (or if it's the original issue)

Comment: This could be related to pulling the data out of `state` *before* you make the async fetches, so that you're always pushing to an empty array after every await finishes.

Comment: That's why you would wait for each iteration, possibly

Comment: Why are you not using one object to save `metas`, `quotes`, `charts` and `stocks` of one product instead of saving them into different arrays?

Comment: @RehanHaider The reason is because I have separate UI components for each of those 4. I want each component to independently have it's own initial "loading" state.

Answer (score 1):

For fetching multiple URLs in parallel using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). A roughly implement in your case would be:

```
_addStock = async symbol => {
    ...
    let fetchMeta = this._fetchMeta.resolve(symbol);
    let fetchQuote = this._fetchQuote.resolve(symbol);
    let fetchMeta = this._fetchChart.resolve(symbol);

    let data = await Promise.all([
      fetchMeta,
      fetchQuote,
      fetchChart,
    ]).then((data) => {
      console.log(data); 
      // Inspect your data here setState accordingly        
      this.setState({ ... });    
    });        
};
```

Answer (score 0):

calling `_addStock` multiple time,call `setState` multiple time.Its cause multiple `setState` operation to run in parallel without waiting  confirmation of previous setState update. As a `setState` async operation, you get such weird behaviour.

To fix it,you can add one more level of `async/await` with `promise`

```
_addStock = async symbol => {

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)){

        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            metas: [...metas, meta],
            quotes: [...quotes, quote],
            charts: [...charts, chart],
            stocks: [...stocks, stock]
        },()=>{

            resolve(true); //give confirmation setState is updates successfully.
        });
    }
};
```

call `_addStock` with `await`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const initStocks = ["FB", "MSFT", "NVDA", "AAPL"];
    initStocks.forEach( async s => {
            await this._addStock(s)
    });
}
```

Comment: It will solve problem but it will not be asynchronous at all and will cause re-renders equal to numbers of new stocks

Comment: @RehanHaider from PO user call setState multiple time.He doesn't mentioned the requirement with setState .Did he want call mutliple time or single. :)

Comment: Calling `setState` multiple times batch all changes and proceed them collectively then `setState` callBacks are invoked and cause one render. When you wait for `setState` state callBack it means you are waiting for re-rendering and than you will update state which will cause another re-render.

Comment: @RehanHaider hope u r getting meaning of my above comments. :D

Comment: I got you, you don't want to improve :D

Comment: @RehanHaider dont mind man,Please add your answer below with improvement.You can downvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you call [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) multiple time in short interval react batch all [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) calls for performance and execute them collectively, that's why when to call [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) 2nd time first request is still pending and component `state` is empty at the end only one item is inserted.

You can use following approach to bring data asynchronously, and it will update state only once with final data. As it is not using state for each iteration that's why it will maintain data consistency too.

```
_addStock = symbols => {
  const { metas, quotes, charts, stocks } = this.state;
  // a variable to keep track how many symbols have been processed
  let count = 0;

  symbols.forEach(async symbol => {
    // check if stock already exists
    const hasStock = stocks.some(s => s.symbol === symbol);
    if (!hasStock) {
      //make all api requests in parallel
      let meta = this._fetchMeta(symbol);
      let quote = this._fetchQuote(symbol);
      let chart = this._fetchChart(symbol);
      let stock = {
        symbol: symbol.toUpperCase(),
        color: setStockColor(),
        display: true
      };

      //wait for responses
      meta = await meta;
      quote = await quote;
      chart = await chart;

      //add all values to old state
      metas.push(meta);
      quotes.push(quote);
      chart.push(chart);
      stock.push(stock);
    }

    //update count
    ++count;

    //if all values have been retrieved update state
    if(count === symbols.length){
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        metas: [...metas],
        quotes: [...quotes],
        charts: [...charts],
        stocks: [...stocks]
      });
    }
  });
};

componentDidMount() {
    const initStocks = ["FB", "MSFT", "NVDA", "AAPL"];
    //Pass whole array to _addStock
    this._addStock(initStocks);
}
```